# problem downloading Shutter in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, downloads, shutter

when I click "download" Shutter for v12.04 in Ubuntu Softwarecenter, a window of Launch Application pops up stating: "This link needs to be opened with an application". I have no clue which application that may be. Do you?

Comment: You can better install it from the software center by tying "shutter" in the search bar in the software center.

Answer (score 1):

The link you clicked will download the .deb file (the packaged version of a software) and you should open it by browsing to the `/usr/bin/` directory and then choosing `software-properties-gtk` as the application to open the link.

It is easier to install shutter using the software center. Open software center by typing "software center" on the dash and then type "shutter" on the search bar and press <kbd>Return</kbd> and then enter your password if prompted and this will install the application for you.

You could also install shutter from the terminal. Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and then type

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

and enter your password if prompted and then type <kbd>Return</kbd> twice to install the application.